# Service Stack API and ThinkTecture.IdentityServer

Tags: claims-based-identity, sts-securitytokenservice

Our team is developing our first web api and using Service Stack to expose our REST services. We know that we need security so these API endpoints are not available to the world. We also know that we need to be able to filter the data returned by these APIs depending on the user that is calling the service. These services will be consumed by our mobile apps and our desktop websites. The user repository is in a Users table in SQL Server, but not part of an ASP.NET Membership Provider implementation. Is the Thinktecture IdentityServer or IdentityModel the appropriate choice for securing our APIs and accessing claims over OAuth? Also, are there some comprehensive examples at implementing these with REST services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. This was a sufficient stack for us to accomplish our needs :)

Comment: Did you find some examples on the internet of how Thinktecture and ServiceStack was used together?

Comment: Nope, we had to roll our own. Basically modifying the IdentityServer to use our user database. Note: At the time we worked with the IdentityServer, it only supported the password grant type for OAuth2.